# Read all divs with class using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can i read all the divs with class using jquery or javascript. I have many divs in my page and some div has child divs as well. I want to read all the divs with class only in the page. How can i read all of them?

Comment: to call all the divs on the page you can use $('div') but what do you mean when you say read exacty?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by read, but you certainly can select them all with `$('div')`.

edit: Like the answers are saying, to select by class you just add `.class_name`. So instead it would be `$('div.class_name')`

Comment: Do you want to get all divs which have a class set or a specific class set?

Comment: @WayneEllery All divs which have a class. Some of my divs have inner divs as well so i want all divs with a class

Comment: some one gave me -1 why?

Comment: @Eran i want to read the class name of each div

Comment: can you please tell us what is the purpose? why do you need to read all of the divs with the class name? so it will be easier to help you...maybe there is a better and simple solution...

Comment: you're getting negative votes because your question is unclear

Comment: @Coder. It's because the question wasn't exactly clear. You need to be careful when asking a question and try to make it as clear as possible. It would have helped if you provided a simple example with what your expected result was

Comment: Not only that but is a very simple thing to look up in the selectors section of the API and at least make an attempt to code it yourself. Hover over the downvote will see tooltip that says `shows lack of research...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very easy in jQuery: `$("div.class")`. It will read all of the `div` elements whose class is `class`.

If you are not after a certain class, but *any* class, you can use the following:

```
$("div[class]");
```

Comment: OP is after all divs which have a class, not a specific class

Comment: @WayneEllery yup exactly i want to read all divs which have a class

Answer (score 1):

The qSA answer is deleted, but you can use the same selector for jQuery and querySelectorAll:

```
var divsWithAClass = document.querySelectorAll('div[class]');
```